# React Native no such method- setCallWebSocket

Tags: react-native

React native android fails -

```
ANR Fatal Exception
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke WebSocketModule.connect
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:382)
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:138)
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:368)
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:138) 
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setCallWebSocket(Lokhttp3/Call;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.corpay.mwallet.sit.dev-2/base.apk:classes23.dex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your react-native bundling server may have become corrupted. Try resetting the local server by killing it and running the following commands in your CMD. Then run your server again.

```
$ rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ yarn cache clean
```

Comment: many times I did the same things always ended up with same error

Comment: am not building a react native project instead am connecting js components with my existing android app and ended up with error(Runtime error)